# E-Mail Contents of a Webpage

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, web

I have a .Net 4.0 web app that contains some dynamic jquery charts and graphs I'd like to be able to email the current contents of a page to a logged in user without any of the functionality something like a printed page they could use for reference.

Basically I want to replicate the javascript window.print() function but email the contents.

I'd like to send the rendered webpage programmatically.

Comment: Send email using the browser or programmatically?

Comment: Programmatically. So they click the E-mail button and it would e-mail the rendered contents of the webpage to their inbox.

Comment: I have never seen something like that. Unless you can wrap the entire page inside a single control, div, or frame.

Comment: The problem with this is that many of the ways to do this directly on the server won't render the javascript.

Comment: Could I do this in the browser via javascript and have Outlook or something email the rendered page?

Comment: is the jquery/javascript on the page changing what's on the page? In other words could a server side script call the url and consume it as it renders?

Comment: yes the jquery changes what is displayed click on tabs and such, rendering graphs

Answer (score 0):

This might do it.

Convert the entire page to PDF

Then send the PDF as an attachment

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7089/Generate-PDF-documents-from-a-HTML-page-using-ASP

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5567/Create-and-manipulate-PDF-documents-100-NET

Comment: don't think this will work since there are graphs displayed using jquery

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution in PHP so I don't know whether this will be of any use. You can use a templating library called Smarty and your normal HTML and Jquery/Javascript into the template and assign data to the variables within the template. And then you can use $smarty->fetch command to retrieve what would be outputted to the browser into a variable instead, and then send the content of the variable in the email.

This is what I do for some of my web apps that need to allow the user to modify the style or add coments via an ajax post.